# Retrieve GraphQL Introspection Schema as http response

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I can generate the Django Graphene [introspection schema](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/introspection/) by using the Django management command as

```
./manage.py graphql_schema --schema tutorial.quickstart.schema --out schema.json
```

How can I return the JSON schema as *HTTP Response* from a view, so that the client is able to view/fetch the same any time?

Comment: What's the unique advantage of using `GraphQL` then `REST` ?

Comment: On this case, or in general?

Comment: Yes! On this case.

Comment: First: This response *should not be queried*, it should be as-is since it is used by some client for typing (for example [Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/) ). Second: This response can not be served with GraphQL since it is reversibly depend on each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`introspect()`**--(GitHub)](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/b685e109f5d085e9861b73400b0802abe9b77545/graphene/types/schema.py#L516) method of the [**`Schema(...)`**--(GitHub)](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/b685e109f5d085e9861b73400b0802abe9b77545/graphene/types/schema.py#L397) class

```
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from tutorial.quickstart import schema


def introspection_schema(request):
    data = {"data": schema.introspect()}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```